# How to detect collision between two sprites with random shapes with libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision

I'm new to libgdx and to game development in general. I'm trying to make a 2D game with libgdx on Android. For now, for detecting collisions I was using rectangles and the "overlaps" method, it worked very well. I now want to add very specific objects into my game that are randomly generated and with various shapes like circles, stars etc.. 
Can you guys help me find a way to detect these kind of collisions ? I heard about Box2D, should I use that ?
Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? To help us help you, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the overlaps method with any polygon. You pass it in as an array of the vertices of the object.